# How can I optimize this code that finds the GCD?

Tags: java, optimization, algorithm, performance

```
int count;
int gcdCount;
int testCase = 5;

while (testCase > 0)
{
    int n = 5;
    count = 0;
    gcdCount = 0;
    // to get two  random numbers a and b a<=n and b<=n
    //get probablity of gcd(a,b) ==b
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            count++;
              // check if gcd(i,j) is equal to second number j
            if (findgcd(i, j) == j)
            {
                gcdCount++;
            }
        }
    }
     //return probability of gcdcount 
    System.out.println(gcdCount + "/" + count);   
    testCase--;
}
```

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of the code?

Comment: I'd recommend the [Euclidean algorithm](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~greenfie/gs2004/euclid.html) for solving this problem as it's more efficient and probably clearer.  You're using nested for-loops, giving you an easy O(n^2) (not a good thing).

Comment: Yes i wanted to optimize the inner for loop as it takes O(n^2) time the gcd part is not a problem i have calculated the gcd using Euclidean Algorithm in findgcd method

Comment: Right, and that algorithm should help.  There's some pseudocode on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `findgcd` is correctly implemented and that `i` and `j` are guaranteed to both be non-negative, `findgcd(i, j) == j` is equivalent to `j != 0 && i % j == 0`. That allows a further optimisation to a single loop, because the number of values in `1..n` which are divisible by `j` is `floor(n/j)`:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
{
    count += n;
    gcdCount += n / j;
}
```

Comment: I did'nt get get it how can you optimize it to one loop

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to increment "count" variable in every loop. The value of it depends on "n".

Here you can find some ways to optimize a loop:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization

What is the difference between the test cases? For me it seems nothing change; you always run the same double for-loop.